# Unable to run "gradlew" with compileOptions set

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am able to build and run my application through Android Studio. However running any gradle commands in the command-line (even with a `./gradlew clean`) fails with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

Removing the following line from build.gradle allows me to build in command-line but not in Android Studio.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I had faced the same problem once before and "Invalidate cache and Restart" worked for me... You will find this option under File->Invalidate cache and Restart... Hope this fix works for you too :-)

Edit: Also, in your project's build.gradle file, check if

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:*.*.*
```

is greater than 2.4.1